# How can I get the names of all nodes or polygons from an fbx file?

Tags: java, unity-game-engine, maya, fbx, 3d-model

I have a 3D character model saved in an FBX format. I want to know the list of names for each model or joint so I can decide if that part of the character is relevant to me or not. I am not using Maya software. I got the 3D model from a third party and I am going to use that model for animation in unity3D but before importing the model in unity3d, I want to know the model label like hair, head etc so is there any way to get the label programmatically from FBX file? Thanks

Comment: Are you still using Maya in this process? If so, we can help you by directing our time towards MEL / Python Scripts in Maya. My solution would be to export a list from Maya with the names of your models, joints, etc.

Comment: I tried with the help of java coding . First I open the file in notepad++ then I found the pattern that after every joint name there is a word "ModelS" but in between the ModelS and joint name there is two null word then I tried with java to print the line which having ModelS word but i dont know what i need to do next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**About FBX format**

"FBX" is a compiled format, created by Autodesk, that can be utilized by a number of 3D Softwares even though FBX is a proprietary file format. Because it is compiled, you will end up with a wide-range of "NULL" format symbols; 
I.E. -

```
€«±µÈ7L—C«‚›ìŸn»yàn´ZÌ'>ï¯Óp>¸z±ú‘uá#OFªƒû·Pð>U>j}jp[7)
```

Because of this, it is better to either export as a **DAE** / *Collada* format or **OBJ** format if you are not utilizing bone structures.

**About Collada / DAE_FBX / DAE format**

This format is open source and was typically used for video games in the past. The file is an **XML** based file and should be easy to manipulate in Java / JavaScript. Because of this, the file offers full support for opening the file up in your favorite notepad program / app... or even your favorite programming language.

Utilizing this format, your geometry will be listed under the child "geometry".

**Potential Solution (Python in Maya)**

If you are using Maya and can inject a bit of code in before exporting the FBX file... Try running this before export (Python):

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

# Create the location and fileName
yourDesktopVar = "C:\\Users\\[Your user]\\Desktop\\"
saveFileName   = "Joints_Models_Groups.txt"
documentToSave = open((yourDesktopVar + saveFileName), "w")

# Setup arrays full of relative information

jointNames     = [jn for jn in cmds.ls(type = "joint")]
meshNames      = [cmds.listRelatives(mn, parent=1)[0] for mn in cmds.ls(type = "mesh")]

# ================================
# Writing Joints
# ================================

documentToSave.write("Joints\n\r")
documentToSave.write("--------------")

for eachJointName in jointNames:
    documentToSave.write(eachJointName + "\n\r")

# Create a blank space
documentToSave.write("\n\r\n\r)

# ================================
# Writing Meshes
# ================================
documentToSave.write("Meshes\n\r")
documentToSave.write("--------------")

for eachMeshName in meshNames:
    documentToSave.write(eachMeshName + "\n\r")
```

Obviously, you'll have to edit this to fit your format, but this will crank out a basic text document that should give you enough information to start with.

Comment: No i am using unity3D and in unity3D i want the list of model joint of the character .

Comment: Well, you added "Maya" as a tag to the post so I assumed you might still be using it. In that case, you'll have to make a script, as you probably already are, in Unity that will get the joint names attached to the specific character.